# CCNode#rotation. RotationX != RotationY. Don't know which one to return

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x

I am getting this error in my cocos2d-x game. I am using getRotation() and setRotataion() function only, so why is my RotationX != RotationY.

Infact I put a break point in all the places where RotationX and RotationY is set and it never reaches those point.

Please let me know what could be the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I got the answer. In setRotation(), somewhere is was sending value NaN. Cocos2d does not give error while setting, it gives error while getting after that.

Comment: Then please close the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. In setRotation(), somewhere is was sending value NaN. Cocos2d does not give error while setting, it gives error while getting after that.

So please check whereever you are setting rotation that might not be a valid value.